# Arduino Wi-Fi shield switch between client and server

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to switch between client and server using an Arduino Wi-Fi [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields)?

That is, switch between `server mode` and `client mode` on the fly on a

```
WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient client;
```

This works for incomming clients, but if I try to use the client to connect to some site with `client.connect(serverName, 80)` ... `client.stop()`, the Arduino will receive the page content of that page, then it will hang, it won't accept any new clients (it won't respond when I use the browser to connect to it.

I tried using a separate WiFiclient for the connect part, but with the same result:

`client = server.available();`... After using connect, this part won't work anymore.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should type your solution into the answer field and accept it so people know the question is answered without having to click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my problem was caused by some bugs in the firmware.

The "old" firmware that was on the shield when I bought it had some problems dealing with client and server running both on the Arduino.

They fixed it and a bunch of other issues since then, so it's best to upgrade the shield's firmware to it's latest revision.

Here is a [guide](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading) on how to do upgrade the firmware on the Arduino WiFiShield.

And here is a [list](https://github.com/arduino/wifishield/issues?state=open) with the issues they fixed.